# Inequality problem

Tags: inequality

What are the values ​​of $B_1, B_2$, and $B_s$ so that the following inequality is satisfied with any value of $U_1$ and $U_2$? where $B_1, B_2, B_s, U_1$, and $U_2 \in \mathbb R^+$

$ B_1 U_1^2 + B_2 U_2^2 < B_s (U_1-U_2)^2 $

Comment: First try $U_1=\cosh^2(x)\quad U_2=\sinh^2(x)$.Hope it helps to clarify something .

Comment: Do you mean only $U_2\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$ ($B_1, B_2, B_s, U_1$ are real numbers)?

Comment: Yes, all the numbers are positive reals

Comment: What if $U_1 = U_2 > 0$ in your inequality?

Comment: It seems that $B_1$ or $B_2$ must be negative. I will review the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $U_2 \neq 0$, consider the quadratic inequality

$$ (B_s - B_1) (\frac{U_1}{U_2} )^2 - 2 B_s (\frac{U_1}{U_2} ) + (B_s - B_2) > 0 $$

---

> This has no real roots, so the necessary and sufficient condition is
>  1. $B_s - B_1 > 0 $,
>  2. $(2B_s)^2 - 4 (B_s - B_1)(B_s - B_2) < 0 $.
>  Can you proceed from here?

$ $

> Deal with $U_2 = 0 $ separately

Conclude that the necessary and sufficient conditions are:

$$B_sB_1 + B_sB_2 - B_1B_2 < 0, B_s > B_1, B_s > B_2$$

Comment: Thanks!!
A single small detail:

Comment: Thanks!!
A single small detail:
In the line
$ (2B_s)^2 - 4 (B_s - B_1) ( B_s - B_2) < 0 $
Hence,
$ B_s(B_1+B_2) - B_1 B_2 < 0 $

Comment: @JonattanSarmiento Ah yes indeed. Fixed.